# Different hashes being printed using echo with and withou -n

Tags: hash, echo, md5, md5sum

Echo is working properly, I just want to understand why the command `echo -n a | md5sum` gives me the **correct hash** for 'a' (which is `0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661`), while `echo a | md5sum` gives me a completely different hash: `60b725f10c9c85c70d97880dfe8191b3`.

The -n option for echo means "do not output the trailing newline".
Why exactly does this change the hash value? What are the processes that occur so that the piped md5sum gives me this other hash? What is the correspondent plaintext for that hash? (I'm running it on an online hash decrypting site, but it's taking quite some time)

The actual value of that hash is not that important (although it could be useful for me to comprehend the working mechanisms): I want to better understand the process, and I can't quite figure out how it works.

Thanks!

Comment: `The -n option for echo means "do not output the trailing newline". Why exactly does this change the hash value?` Because `a` !== `a plus a newline`. `What are the processes that occur so that the piped md5sum gives me this other hash?` An additional newline character. `What is the correspondent plaintext for that hash?` Again, `a` followed by a newline.

Comment: @tkausl  I input ```echo -en "a\n" | md5``` and got that same resulting hash: 60b725f10c9c85c70d97880dfe8191b3 . Thanks a lot for the clear, precise and didactic answer, it helped a lot!